# bind event to the dynamic html in angular 2

Tags: html, angular

Can anyone tell me how to accomplish the click event binding to the html which comes as a response from service and then want to append that html to component  with the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Same way as you would use  in a template inline

```
(event)="statement".
```

Comment: Angular bindings are not processed at all in dynamically added HTML. Angular only processes what is statically added to component templates.

Comment: can you please suggest me that  how can  i attach the click event to h1 tag which is coming from service (i.e everytime there will different html will come as a response from service) so i need to find the specific tag from that response and then bind the click event to that.
Following is the sample code 
http://plnkr.co/edit/f4XKhd42OR8TBazKV9ex